# Implementing Rock, Paper, Scissors tournament in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to implement a rock-paper-scissors tournament using the language, as an exercise.

The rps_game_winner method that's called within the code below returns the winner in a pair of competitors.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  qualifying_round_winners = []
  for i in 0..0
  tournament.each_with_index do |x, xi|
    x.each_with_index do |y, yi|
      winner = rps_game_winner(y)
      qualifying_round_winners.push(winner) 
      qualifying_round_winners = qualifying_round_winners.each_slice(2).to_a
    end
  end
  tournament = qualifying_round_winners.each_slice(2).to_a
  end
  return tournament 
end
```

This is the input I provide:

```
puts rps_tournament_winner([
 [
   [ ["Armando", "P"], ["David", "S"] ],
   [ ["Richard", "R"],  ["Michael", "S"] ]
 ]

])
```

The output I get is:

```
David
S
Richard
R
```

This is where I get stuck. I'm unable to get these two compete against each other, and declare the final winner.

As you can see in the code above, the terminating condition of the for loop needs attention.

Any help?

Comment: A recursive solution might be easier, especially if you have to handle arbitrarily deep brackets. I'll leave it at that for now since this is tagged "homework".

Comment: advice: use more expression maps/select/... and less statements for/each.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some modifications in your code.

**Note:** If I give `[ ["Armando", "P"], ["David", "S"] ]` as input to my `rps_game_winner()` function it will give result like `["David", "S"]`.

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  qualifying_round_winners = []
  for i in 0..0
  tournament.each_with_index do |x, xi|
    x.each_with_index do |y, yi|
      winner = rps_game_winner(y)
      qualifying_round_winners.push(winner) 
    end
  end
  tournament = rps_game_winner(qualifying_round_winners)
  end
  return tournament 
end
```

So for your input

```
[[ [["Armando", "P"], ["David", "S"]], [["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"]] ]]
```

it will also return a result like `["Richard", "R"]`.